# Changing layout of 3 div columns to 2 div columns and 3rd one below

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rearrange 3 divs when device width is below 900px. They are arranged as three columns (2 floating divs and main one in the middle) and i don't know how to make them be 2 columns and third div below them ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAsZh.jpg) shows what i'm aiming at).
Thank you in advance :)

Adding code as you asked :) here is html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is css

```
#container{
width: 90%;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto ;
}
header{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;

}
#left{
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 500px;
background-color: orange;
}
#right{
float: right;
width: 20%;
height: 500px;
background-color: green;
}
#middle{
width: 80%;
background-color: red;
height: 500px;

}
```

if i make right div float:none then it moves the middle div

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Please also post the minimal amount of code to show us what you have.

Comment: You'd propably provide a small fiddle so we can help you directly.

Comment: I added some code hope it helps you get the idea that i have

Comment: And thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of {in an ominous voice} [RESPONSIVE DESIGN](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp) ! ,

To perform what you are trying to do you will need to explore [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Here is an example of what you are trying to do: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrokenRobot/q4kjs1Lq/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
   left content flexible width
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   right content fixed width
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
   Bottom content flexible width
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
   float: left;
  background: #00FF00;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background: #0000ff;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
  float: right;
  background: #ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .left {
    float: left;
    background: #00ff00;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .right {
    float: none;
    width: 75%;
    background: #0000ff;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .bottom {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    background: #ff0000;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    display: inherit;
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use media queries
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

With media queries and [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Here is a snippet, (click on run then full screen).

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="sub c">1</div>
    <div class="sub c">2</div>
    <div class="doge c">3</div>
</div>
```

```css
    .flex{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .c{
      height:20px;
      width:20px;
      border: 1px solid green;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      }

    @media(max-width:600px){
     .sub{
        width: 50%;
      }
     .doge{
        width: 100%
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="sub c"></div>
  <div class="sub c"></div>
  <div class="doge c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I advise you don't use display flex, because on IE 9, it doesn't work
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: It did the trick.. Thanks for the help! i'l wait to see if anyone else has some other answer before accepting...

Comment: And my vote does not change the publicly displayed score because i have less than 15 for my score

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your sourcecode to tell you why it has not worked. At least you could describe it in more detail. Otherwise I would suspect that clear: both could maybe help you here by redefining a div-class in a media-query. At least this has worked for me.

As an example you could just attach float: left for the left column then the middle column would be following on the right side. By redefining the right-column (class) with clear: both the right-column would then be a footer. This is just an example and would not be the best solution indeed.

Comment: Well, this answer is a borderline between an actual answer / a comment; you should really wait until the OP posts more information.

Comment: You could add my answer to your code by just adding float left to the id's called "left" and "middle" and redefine "right" inside of a media-query by adding clear: both just like I've said. Of course right would then have to be also defined for devices with a width > 900px. The other solution posted above by Ced is interesting. Good night (?).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it.

```css
/* Styles go here */

body,html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
}


.wrapper{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.div1{
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  background-color:orange;
}

.div2{
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  margin-left:2%;
  background-color:red;
  
}

.div3{
  height:100%;
  width:30%;
  margin-left:2%;
  float:left;
  background-color:green;
}

@media(max-width:900px){
  
  .wrapper{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
  
  .div1{
    height:70%;
    width:49%;
    float:left;
    background-color:orange;
  }
  
  .div2{
    height:70%;
    width:49%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    
  }
  
  .div3{
    height:30%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 0 20px 0;
    background-color:green;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="div1"><p></p></div>
      <div class="div2"><p></p></div>
      <div class="div3"><p></p></div>
</div>
```